# Payment instrument type is not accepted by this merchant account. PayPal Express Checkout / Braintree PHP SDK

Tags: php, laravel-5, paypal, braintree

I'm receiving this error when I make a PayPal Express Checkout transaction using Braintree PHP SDK:

```
"Payment instrument type is not accepted by this merchant account."
```

[These](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/validation-errors/all/php#code-91902) are the details of the error:

"*When providing a payment method token, your merchant account must be configured to accept the payment method type represented by the token.*"

This is the code:

```
public function createPayPalGateway() {
    $gateway = new \Braintree_Gateway(array(
        'accessToken' => 'access_token$production$**',
    ));
    return $gateway;
}
        // Charge Nonce
        $result = $gateway->transaction()->sale([
          'amount' =>$amount,
          'paymentMethodNonce' => $nonce,
          'options' => [
            'submitForSettlement' => True
          ]
        ]);
```

However, how do I implement this configuration? Is it something in the code? I don't have access to the PayPal account, the manager just sent me the access token.

Comment: This error might be related to the merchant account configuration, I recommend you reach out to Braintree Support support@getbraintree.com. They will likely require your [merchant ID](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/important-gateway-credentials#merchant-id).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your Braintree account is set up, you might need to pass along the `merchantAccountId` when you create your transaction.

```
transaction()->sale([
  'amount' =>$amount,
  'paymentMethodNonce' => $nonce,
  'merchantAccountId' => $yourMerchantAccountId,
  'options' => [
    'submitForSettlement' => True
  ]
])
```

You can reference this in the Braintree docs.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Please do not attached links in your answers. What if link gets expired?

Comment: Thanks, Nisarg! That's a good point. I've updated my answer to exclude links.

Comment: Actually there is nothing wrong with linking to external material in a SO answer, as long as you also copy and paste the relevant info/code snippets into the answer. In fact, it's encouraged. Dead links can always be updated. Source: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659